# Why does the program print 0.00

Tags: c

The problem proposed is this:
"Create a problem which calculates the consumption of energy during 2 months considering the next:

1. If the waste is less than 1000kw per hour multiply times 1.2
2. If the waste is between 1000 and 1850 kw per hour multiply times 1.2 too.
3. If the waste is greater than 1850kw per hour multiply times 0.9

I wrote this program and when I run it and add the values of the waste and hours, the fee gives me back 0.00 no matter which value I enter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
   int c; //energy waste//
   float p, h; // p=fee h=hours//

   printf("Introduce el consumo y el numero de horas:");
   scanf("%d %f ", &c, &h);

   if (c<1000) {
        p=h*1.2;
   }
   if ((c=1000) && (c<1851)) {
        p=h*1.2;
   }
   if (c>1850) {
        p=h*0.9;
   }

   printf("Fee: %f", p);
   return 0;
}
```

I need to get the fee. I hope it's well written because I speak spanish and ain't familiarized with progrmming concepts in english very well.

Comment: `if((c=1000)` part doesn't do what you expected it to do.

Answer (score 7):

```
if ( ( c = 1000 ) && ( c < 1851 ) ) {
```

should be

```
if ( ( c >= 1000 ) && ( c <= 1850 ) ) {
```

You probably had a typo and typed `=` instead of `>`

When you use

```
if( ( c = 1000 ) && ( c < 1851 ) ){
```

You are assigning `1000` to `c`.

---

Comment: I think it should be `c >= 1000`, otherwise the expression doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg , you are right. I made the change. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're using an assignment operator, instead of checking if two operands are equal. Change

```
if((c=1000) && (c<1851))
```

to

```
if((c==1000) && (c<1851))
```

Plus, the second condition is pointless, since `c` already has to be smaller than 1851 if it is equal to 1000.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use 'if else if structure' in case of multiple condition.
you use only if statements that work independently.
correct code for your problem is given below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

    int c; //energy waste//

    float p=0, h; // p=fee h=hours//

    printf("enter energy waste \n");

    scanf("%d",&c);

    printf("enter hours\n");
    scanf("%f",&h);
    if (c<1000){
        p=h*1.2;
    }
    else if((c>=1000)&&(c<1851)){
        p=h*1.2;}
    else if(c>1850){
        p=h*0.9;
    }
    else{
         printf("you enter wrong energy waste data\n");
    }
    printf("Fee: %f", p);
    return 0;
}
```